# ADMIN-BADPATHNAMESPACE Marklogic Error

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to deploy an application, and it keeps failing due to a "**ADMIN-BADPATHNAMESPACE**" error.  It tells me it's due to a MarkLogic module for **json** error.

I looked up the file that this json.xqy was trying to be imported into, and I have a file that imports MarkLogic's json functions this way:

```
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
    at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";
```

The error message doesn't help much, and so I'm confused where to go from here.

Comment: How were you deploying the application?

Comment: @DaveCassel using mvn

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to define the path to that json file in your admin settings.  Do this:

1. See what database is having the problem.  Your error stack trace should give you a database id.  If you don't know what that id maps to, use the **xdmp:database-name($id)** function in your qConsole to see what the string name of your database is.
2. Go to your admin settings console (for me that is **localhost:8001**)
3. Go to "**Databases**" > "**DB_NAME**" (found in step 1) > "**Path Namespaces**" > "**Add**"
4. Enter in your prefix and namespace uri

   - For instance, for your json problem, do **prefix:json** and **namespace uri: http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/json**

That should solve your problem.